# Port for HTTP and Websocket in GlassFish

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish-4

1. I am using Glassfish 4.0 with Eclipse.I have been trying to use Websockets.
2. I tried code from [here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websocket-multiple-users-encoders-decoders-dogs/) and it worked .
3. Then I tried to integrate it in my Servlet application.
4. Application name is CollabEdit.
   I created server for Websockets and mapped it to url `/echo`.

   ```
   @ServerEndpoint("/echo") 
   public class OTServerr {}
   ```
5. Therefore, at client end, Here is what I did :

   ```
   var link = "ws://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/echo";
      var webSocket = new WebSocket(link);
   ```

But I get an error here that says:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/echo' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Is there something wrong with what I am doing ? Is it by anychance port number issue ?

6. I call rest of the servlets in my application as
   "http://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/servletMapping";

Comment: did you use @ServerEndpoint("/path") annotation?

Comment: @user993553: Yes, I did.

Comment: does ws://localhost:8080/echo respond?

Comment: @user993553: No it does not. When I explicitly try calling this URL, browser renders Disallowed/bad url scheme . Neither it is called using new WebSocket(link). I get 404.